# Testing S3 upload with Laravel Medialibrary "The current request does not have a file in a key named"

Tags: php, laravel, testing, media-library

I'm writing a feature test for a simple photo upload to S3 using Laravel Medialibrary.

This is the test:

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_upload_a_photo()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    Storage::fake('s3');

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->signIn($user);

    $this->post( route('users.update.photo', [
        $user,
        'photo' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo.jpeg', 500, 500)->size(1000),
    ]));

    $this->assertEquals(1, Media::all()->count());

    Storage::disk('s3')->assertExists('photo.jpeg');
}
```

and this is the relevant part of the controller method handling the upload:

```
public function uploadPhoto(User $user, Request $request)
{

    // ...

    try {
        $user->addMediaFromRequest('photo')
            ->preservingOriginal()
            ->toMediaCollection('user-photo');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
        Log::debug('User photo upload: ' . $e);

    }

    return redirect(route('users.edit.profile', $user));
}
```

The error catched there with `dd($e)` is

**The current request does not have a file in a key named `photo`**

I actually can test out that the error message is true with putting right in front of the try-catch:

`dd($request->has('photo'));` === *true*

but

`dd($request->hasFile('photo'));` === *false*

So I do not attach my mock file properly as a file to the request obviously, but I can't figure out how to do that and every example around my online searches suggest doing the test the way I already do.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try this syntax for the call `$this->post( route('users.update.photo', ['user' => $user]), [ 'photo' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo.jpeg', 500, 500)->size(1000), ]);`

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot. not sure why i cant mark your comment as correct answer.

Comment: Ok, it's just a comment. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post()` method expects the url as the first argument, and the data as the second argument.

You are using the helper `route()` to generate the url, which expects the user you want to edit as a parameter, but you are also passing the file data as a parameter to the helper `route()`, instead of passing it as an argument to the `post()` method:

```
$this->post( // just one argument for the post method
    route('users.update.photo', [ // and two parameters for the route helper
        $user,
        'photo' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo.jpeg', 500, 500)->size(1000),
    ])
);
```

So use this syntax to pass the file as second argument for the `post()` method:

```
$this->post( 
    route('users.update.photo', ['user' => $user]), // first argument
    [ 'photo' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo.jpeg', 500, 500)->size(1000) ]  // second argument
);
```